# How to share an object between two Models in MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, model-view-controller, model

I have two Models in my card game.

1. HandModel - contains the list of instances of CardModel.
2. BoardModel - contains instances of CardModel placed on the board with specific coordinates.

I want to pop a card instance from the HandModel list and place it in the BoardModel coordinates. I would like to send a Card between those two models, but I don't want to directly call BoardModel inside HandModel just for this reason. Not sure how should I do it.

Comment: In the controller part of the MVC you might get the CardModel from the HandModel and pass it to the BoardModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to design your model in a way in which the card model itself has some kind of location which can be updated by a controller which handles the cards. That way no model has to know any other model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Definitely gives me some ideas. The only problem is that I still need BoardModel to know about those card instances. It will have to manipulate their data according to their coordinates.

Comment: I mean I could combine all the models in a single controller. The other option that I have in mind is to send Notification from one model into another, then controller wont have to take so many dependencies. Also I could combine HandModel with BoardModel into a big Model. Still not sure which approach I should take.

Comment: The board model only has to know the ID of a card instance... you do not need to save the whole instance of the model. The controller knows all instances whereas the models itself only know some kind of relations. Such a relation could be something like BoardModel.contains(CardID1, CardID2...). The controller then resolves the ID to an instance and can work with it. The controller also has to update these relations.

Comment: Another option was to introduce an own model for that relations: Location('CardID1', 'Board1'), Location('CardID2', 'Hand1'). In that case, the controller has to update the Location model

Comment: Thank you Markus. I used your advice and created a separate class which stores the positions and instances. It seems flexible enough approach for my solution. Thanks.